# java.lang.VerifyError on org.apache.velocity.app.VelocityEngine

Tags: java, jboss, migration, velocity

We've been working on a long application server migration project, almost finished the technical parts, we've been through the test process of the entire USER_STORIES and we keep getting some bad results when it comes to a specific functionality.

Details Below

> **Caused by: java.lang.VerifyError: (class: org/apache/velocity/runtime/log/Log4JLogChute, method: isLevelEnabled signature: (I)Z) Incompatible argument to function**

This Error is thrown at this specific peace of code

```
        public VelocityLoaderApi() throws Exception {
            ve = new VelocityEngine();
            ve.init();
        }
```

we're using the corresponding dependency

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.velocity</groupId>
            <artifactId>velocity</artifactId>
            <version>1.7</version>
        </dependency>
```

This **init** function works fine in the previous technical layer -> java 6, WebLogic but it keeps crushing after the upgrade to **java 8 & WildFly 10.0.0.Final**

This is a blocking situation, hope find some answers.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What are your log dependencies?

Comment: officialy we're using slf4j to keep the default log solution provided by wildfly

Comment: you could switch to velocity 2.0, which *does* use slf4j...